# How to sort dropdown menu with AM and PM times in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, sorting, time

The code below is filling the dropdown menu with time-based options based on a condition. The problem is that the sorting order is wrong: when I add `10 am` to `1 pm`, it is working fine. When I update the time and add another `am` time, then it shows below `pm`.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.times.length; i++) {
  //var timeFrom = new Date(data.times[i].TimeFrom)
  var timeTo = new Date(data.times[i].TimeTo)
  var iTime = new Date(data.times[i].TimeFrom)
  
  console.log(data.times[i].diffrence);
  
  while (timeTo >= iTime) {
    var formate = iTime.toLocaleTimeString();
    //data.times[i].PK_ID
    var option = '<option value="' + formate + '">' + formate + '</option>';
    
    $('#times').append(option).sortable();
    iTime.setMinutes(iTime.getUTCMinutes() + data.times[i].diffrence)
  }
}
```

Comment: better you take time list in 24hrs format  or checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52360398/6694635

Comment: Why was this tagged [tag:.net]? I see no relation to that. Your description is hard to understand; I tried editing it, but it’s still unclear what “condition” you’re referring to. `timeTo >= iTime`? In any case, you need to separate data and presentation. Your time _data_ should be `0`, `1`, …, `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`, …, `22`, `23`. In the _presentation_, these values may then be mapped to `12 am`, `1 am`, …, `11 am`, `12 pm`, `1 pm`, `2 pm`, …, `10 pm`, `11 pm`. The `value` attribute of `<option>` tags is for data, not presentation. Then you can sort by data numerically.